# sns automatically register endpoints to topic

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, amazon-sns

I have built an app for ios and android using phonegap. I am using the sns api to create endpoints and register the tokens for the different Apps in aws. I need the endpoints of the APPs to subscribe to a topic, so we can send out a general message to both ios and android. Is there a way to automatically do this in the sns dashboard or will I need to do this using the api?

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a similar problem and [based on the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-devicetoken.html) you will have to subscribe each client using the API as you receive the push notification credentials for either GCM or APNS. You can prime the system by bulk uploading tokens through CSV files or using the bulkupload API (see "To upload several tokens using the CreatePlatformEndpoint API" in the [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-devicetoken.html) for an example).

You probably also do not want to embed AWS credentials in your mobile application so having some sort of platform backend where the mobile application submits its push credentials (essentially a proxy) and those credentials are ferried over to AWS SNS for various topics is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. To use this code you will need to create your IAM credentials.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{    
    ...
        //Push Notification register
        UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
        UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

        // Sets up the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS
        // Initialize the Amazon credentials provider
        AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSStaticCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithAccessKey:AWSAccessID secretKey:AWSSecretKey];

        AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:DefaultServiceRegionType
                                                                             credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

        [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

...
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
{       
        NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
        NSString *deviceTokenString = [[[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:deviceTokenString forKey:@"deviceToken"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        AWSSNS *sns = [AWSSNS defaultSNS];
        AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput *request = [AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput new];
        request.token = deviceTokenString;
        request.platformApplicationArn = SNSPlatformApplicationArn;
        [[[sns createPlatformEndpoint:request] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task)
        {
            AWSSNSSubscribeInput *subReq = [AWSSNSSubscribeInput new];
            if (task.error != nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@",task.error);
            }
            else
            {
                AWSSNSCreateEndpointResponse *createEndPointResponse = task.result;
                NSLog(@"endpointArn: %@",createEndPointResponse);
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:createEndPointResponse.endpointArn forKey:@"endpointArn"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

                //subscribe to topic
                subReq.endpoint = createEndPointResponse.endpointArn;
                subReq.topicArn = SNSTopicArn;
                subReq.protocols = @"application";
            }
            return [sns subscribe:subReq];
        }] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task)
        {
            if (task.cancelled)
                NSLog(@"Task Cancelled");
            else if (task.error)
                NSLog(@"Error: [%@]", task.error);
            else
                NSLog(@"Success");

            return nil;
        }];
}
```